# How can I attributively express a place's population?

Tags: grammar, modifiers

I guess I can't just say, for example, '4,000,000 Los Angeles', i.e. simply put a numeral as a modifier. There's the word 'strong' that can be used for this purpose but, I believe, for different contexts, for instance 'a 10,000 strong crowd'. What are my options for my case?

Comment: Is it possible for a little bit of context - maybe the wider sentence you are putting this in? I have a few ideas but no idea if they would work in the sentence you are constructing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, [**strong**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/strong) is just fine in this context.

> [Merriam-Webster]
>   **4** : of a specified number
>   // an army ten thousand strong

It can come either before or after the city:

> They visited the *4,000,000-strong* Los Angeles.
>   Los Angeles is *4,000,000 strong*.

In that context, it's assumed to be referring to the population. In fact, I can think of no simpler way of saying it, especially not adjectivally.

Comment: 'The'? Why 'the'? You don't use articles with names of cities

Comment: @SergeyZolotarev You can use articles when a noun is preceded by an adjective. In fact, there are many constructions where omitting an article before [adjective + noun] is unidiomatic. The first sentence in my answer would not be idiomatic without an article (although *a* could also have been used), but the second would not be idiomatic with one.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you can't just put a number with a place without any other context and have people assume it means population. You'd need to be specific or add context. You could do that in a number of ways

- You could refer to **4,000,000 Los Angeles residents**
- You could say "**Los Angeles, population: 4,000,000**"

If you had established the context in a previous statement then you could perhaps just show the place and the number as metric and an attribute, for example, if it were part of a headed list:

> Cities by population:
>
> - Tokyo, 13,515,271
> - Los Angeles, 3,976,322

You could do similar in a paragraph of text without a list. Once you establish you are talking about population you don't need to keep repeating it, for example:

> The population of Tokyo (13,515,271) is greater than that of Los Angeles (3,976,322). London (8,900,000) sits somewhere in the middle of these two.

Comment: I want to use a place as an object and denote its population attributively — because I don't want to create an additional clause and make my sentence harder to process. '[sentence] (thereby including [numerical modifier] [name of a place]) [sentence continues]'

Comment: @SergeyZolotarev Then you need to establish what that attribute is. A place and a number could be anything - gross financial worth, how many metres above sea level, combined IQ. My second suggestion is the shortest, by including the word "population". If you have other places to name then my final suggestion of a list means you only have to establish once that you are talking about population.

Comment: Please give an example

Comment: No, I mean an example of what you described in your comment. If what you described is what is included in your answer then it's not an answer to my question (I need an antepositional modifier)